How many days does the original Evil Dead trilogy take place over?
Assuming we take Evil Dead 2 (and its depiction of the events of Evil Dead 1 during the opening few minutes) and Army of Darkness as a continuous sequence of events, how many days does Ashley Williams experience between arriving at the cabin and taking the potion to return to his own time?

At my own rough count, I think it's approximately a week?

Day 1 (Evil Dead): Ash arrives at the cabin somewhere in the morning or afternoon, awakening the deadites that evening.
Day 2 (Evil Dead 2): Ash is temporarily possessed during sunrise, then stays in the cabin until the archeologist's daughter and company arrives and the deadites return that evening.
Day 3 (Army of Darkness): Ash arrives in the 1300s, is imprisoned, and is proclaimed the chosen one.

Past this point the exact period of time anything takes gets fuzzy; it seems like he spends the evening of Day 3 preparing and building his new hand, rides out on Day 4, spends much of the evening in the windmill, recovers the necronomicon, and then returns to the castle. The next we hear from a scout, the deadite army is 2 days away, so Day 5 and Day 6 are spent preparing, with the battle happening the evening of Day 6, and then he rides out to take the potion and return to his own time on Day 7.
Possible issues with this interpretation include it being somewhat ambiguous how many days take place between Ash being proclaimed the chosen one and leaving for the graveyard to recover the necronomicon, the deadite army being 2 days ride away but Ash appearing to make the trip and back in only a single day, and it being unclear how many days take place between Ash defeating the deadite army and returning to his own time.
